# Dynamic /etc/resolv.conf file?

Tags: server, dns, resolv.conf

I have several Ubuntu servers. Two of them are working as DNS servers. One of my name servers (let's call it DNS1) went down for maintenance. 
I sill had another DNS server running (DNS2).

All other servers are configured to use the nameservers as follows

`/etc/resolv.conf` :

```
nameserver DNS1
nameserver DNS2
```

I can still resolve DNS names using the DNS2 server, but the name resolution takes a long time. It is clear to me that any given server is first trying to access DNS1, and then it is trying DNS2 after failure.

I tried to swap the two lines. The name resolution became too fast.

I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically change the `resolv.conf` file based on the state of the configured nameservers. Of course, I can write a shell script myself to do the job. But I prefer to find a better way if there is one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No a direct solution but you can smooth things a little by adding options to your `resolv.conf` for instance :

```
nameserver DNS1
nameserver DNS2

options rotate
options timeout:2
options attempts:1
```

the default for `timeout` is 5 seconds, and default value for `attempts` is 2.

Comment: Glad I could help.